# MongoDB Query filtering on SubArray IDs

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Suppose I have the 3 collections in MongoDB below.  Assume the "commitment_id" value is the Object_ID of "My Commitment" and the "id" values in the funds array refer to "My Fund" and "His Fund".  How do I get the list of funds referred to in the funds array of the commitment_attributes collection?  From everything I've read it seems like I would need to loop through the cursor and get each one by one, but is there a way to do this in a query automatically?

```
db.commitments.insert({ 
   commitment_nm : "My Commitment",
        due_dt : "1/1/2016",
        ccy: "USD"
    });

db.funds.insert({
    name: "My Fund",
    ccy_iso_cd: "USD"

}, {
    name: "His Fund",
    ccy_iso_cd: "EUR",
})

db.commitment_attributes.insert({
    "commitment_id": ObjectId("56fdd7e371d53780e4a63d58"),
    "attribute_nm": "Original Commitment",
    "effective_dt": "1/10/2016",
    "funds": [ 
        {
            "id": ObjectId("56fdd78c71d53780e4a63d57"),
            "amount": 1000
        }, 
        {
            "id": ObjectId("56fdd78c71d53780e4a63d57"),
            "amount": 500
        }
    ]
})

var commitment = db.commitments.findOne({commitment_nm: "My Commitment"})
var attribute = db.commitment_attribtues.findOne({"commitment_id" : commitment._id});

var funds = ...... want to query for only the funds which have their ID mentioned in the attribute var
```

Comment: There are quite a few ways. Various framworks already implement on top of this by using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) with a list built from iterating the prior result(s) and then replacing the "joined" data in the objects. Of course there is also [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in modern versions of MongoDB. And then of course there is also the consideration that maybe you should be embedding all data to begin with. Too many approaches for a definitive answer here.

Comment: I don't think embedding the data to begin with is viable, there are too many data points for funds alone and they are referenced everywhere, not just by "commitments".  Funds have a 1:N commitment ratio, and commitments have a 1:N commitment:fund ratio, but not every fund may be in a commitment and vice versa.  I think my question was more geared on how to do this strictly in the mongo shell, without any frameworks.  I tried to use $in on the cursor, but that gave me an error.